# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Unspecified error while SSAS cube processing

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ssas, cube

I am new to this please help, I am not sure if this problem is related to SSAS cube processing or something else. Please help.

1. The system was working fine.
2. Some error about bad block occurred

> has a bad block. that is [Drive D and Drive H]
> The file system structure on the disk is corrupt and unusable. Please run the chkdsk
> utility on the volume STORAGE Volume.

```
    Drive D  is where the MySQL installation is located.
```

3. Then as a corrective action we replaced a disk with new one .
4. Cube reset was done as it was suspected data was corrupted by faulty disk.
5. After  disk  replacement and cube reset the errors have changed

> ```
>     Problem executing statement: SELECT statement 
>     Thu, 09 Nov 2017 15:30:05 System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Unspecified error
>      at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
>      at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>      at DMTcommon.DBOps.RunNonQuerySQL(Int32 dbType, String& sql)
>
>     Thu, 09 Nov 2017 15:30:05 Rejecting Files older than 20120201     
>     Thu, 09 Nov 2017 15:30:05 Error in Bulk Insert:
>     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'temp_table'.
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResul  result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>     at DMTcommon.TransferFileObject.callParallelBulkInsert()
> ```

Further Analysis :-

After further analysis it is found that following query is failing to execute when tried directly on database

```
    Problem executing statement: SELECT  <some 95 columns>  INTO dbo.SUR_20171109_201711091530 FROM SUR_template 
Thu, 09 Nov 2017 15:30:05 System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Unspecified error
```

we also observed folowing :-

> 1. Above query is successfully executing in other system.
> 2. simple create query with few columns is successfully creating the table
> 3. The query with few columns executes successfully but when we tried to execute again same query with few columns as before and with
>    different SUR_date_time table name, it fails.

any ideas why is it happening?

Comment: So where should temp_table be defined?

Comment: in the same database I think it is getting created at the time of query execution as we used INTO clause

Comment: This is temp_table name ->  SUR_20171109_201711091530

Comment: Check cube data source availability by processing dimensions individually. Thus you may get additional information; update post if applicable. By now it looks like problem with data source access.

Comment: When I executed DBCC CHECKTABLE('SUR_template')  it returned following


_Msg 5256, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: alloc unit ID 0, page (1:41198625) contains an incorrect page ID in its page header. The PageId in the page header = (0:0).

Msg 7985, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
system Table pre-cheks: object ID 3, could not read and latch page (1:41198625) with latch type SH. Check statement terminated due to unrepairable error._ 

is problem with SQL server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with database.
The database was corrupted somehow.
Thanks for your responses. I really appreciate it. Thanks.